# Ним-2 v2.0 - задача

Tags: python

Имеется задача:

---

Игра ним для двух игроков с двумя кучами и без ограничения на количество забираемых камней.
Напишите программу с «искусственным интеллектом» (ИИ), которая играет против пользователя и выигрывает, если может. Исходное количество камней в кучах задаёт пользователь, программа всегда ходит первой. Выигрывает забравший последний камень, и при окончании игры нужно объявить победителя.
Алгоритм игры выглядит следующим образом:

Сначала пользователь вводит количества камней в кучах (натуральные числа, каждое на новой строке).
Затем первый ход делает программа и выводит через пробел четыре числа: из какой кучи взяты камни; сколько камней взято; сколько камней осталось в кучах, сначала в первой, затем во второй.
Затем ход делает пользователь: вводит на отдельных строках номер кучи и количество камней, которые он хочет взять.
Если ход некорректный, например, пользователь пытается взять камней больше, чем есть в куче, программа должна вывести: Некорректный ход: <куча> <кол-во камней> и ожидать нового ввода пользователя.
После каждого корректного хода игрока или ИИ нужно выводить четыре числа, как и после первого хода ИИ.
Если выигрывает игрок, то надо вывести фразу: Вы выиграли!, а если ИИ – фразу: ИИ выиграл!
Все сообщения программы должны строго соответствовать условию.

Формат ввода
Для старта игры вводятся два натуральных числа.
Пример диалога игры:

10
10
2 1 10 9
1
15
Некорректный ход: 1 15
2
10
Некорректный ход: 2 10
2
7
2 7 10 2
1 8 2 2
2
1
2 1 2 1
1 1 1 1
1
1
1 1 0 1
2 1 0 0
ИИ выиграл!
Примечания
Данная задача дополнительно проверяется преподавателем.
Обратите внимание, что ИИ в выводе не показывает получаемые данные от игрока.

---

К ней есть код, который выполняет свою работу, игра работает, но с одним недостатком, если пользователь введет некорректную цифру, то программу "заклинит" и она на каждое действие будет писать - Неверный ход.
Также в LMS выдается ошибка:

```
stdout:
/bin/sh ./build.sh 1>&2


stderr:
ИИ не умеет считать: 1 + 2 != 2
Completion status: ABNORMAL_EXIT
Term sig: null
Error code: 2
```

Вот сам код:

```
stone1 = int(input())
stone2 = int(input())
stnum = int(0)
take = int(0)
while stone1 != 0 or stone2 != 0:
    if stone1 == 0:
        stnum == 2
    elif stone2 == 0:
        stnum = 1
    else:
        stnum = 1
    if stnum == 1:
        take = 1
        stone1 -= take
    elif stnum == 2:
        take = 1
        stone2 -= take
    print(stnum, take, stone1, stone2)
    if stone1 == 0 and stone2 == 0:
        print('ИИ выиграл!')
    else:
        stnum = int(input())
        take = int(input())
        if stnum == 1:
            while not (1 <= take <= stone1 and take <= stone1):
                print('Некорректный ход:', stnum, take)
                stnum = int(input())
                take = int(input())
            stone1 -= take
        elif stnum == 2:
            while not (1 <= take <= stone2 and take <= stone2):
                print('Некорректный ход:', stnum, take)
                stnum = int(input())
                take = int(input())
            stone2 -= take
        print(stnum, take, stone1, stone2)
        if stone1 == 0 and stone2 == 0:
            print('Вы выиграли!')
```

Comment: В целом, программа отлично работает, но если например в первой куче осталось 0 камней а пользователь берет оттуда 2 (например), то программу заклинит, и каждый ввод будет по ее мнению неправильным.

Comment: так проверяйте, когда выбрана первая куча, что там что-то есть. и так же со второй

Comment: @splash58 проверка есть, но с ней что-то не так

Comment: И по идее LMS - ИИ не умеет считать, но что это значит..?

Comment: Ясно что не так - вы же ее в скобки not вставили

Comment: это значит, что вы неправильное состояние после хода отправили

Comment: А как тогда сделать, если проверку из скобок убрать, тогда можно будет из кучки в 2 камня взять хоть 50.

Comment: И LMS пишет, что "ИИ НЕ УМЕЕТ СЧИТАТЬ, 1+1!=1"

Comment: Кстати, если взять из одной кучи неправильное кол-во, а потом правильное, но из другой, то программа заберет из той кучи в который мы ввели изначально неправильное.

Comment: я немного поправил код. пишу прям тут :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, программа скучная, поскольку нет никакой стратегии. Но если немго разобраться в ваших условиях, она станет более управляемой

```
stone1 = int(input())
stone2 = int(input())

while stone1 * stone2 != 0:
    if stone1 == 0:
        stnum = 2
        take = 1
        stone2 -= take
    else:
        stnum = 1
        take = 1
        stone1 -= take
    print(stnum, take, stone1, stone2)
    if stone1 + stone2 == 0:
        print('ИИ выиграл!')
    else:
        while True:
            stnum = int(input())
            take = int(input())
            if stnum == 1:
                if stone1 and 1 <= take <= stone1:
                    stone1 -= take
                else:
                    print('Некорректный ход:', stnum, take)
                    continue
            elif stnum == 2:
                if stone2 and 1 <= take <= stone2:
                    stone2 -= take
                else:
                    print('Некорректный ход:', stnum, take)
                    continue
            break
        print(stnum, take, stone1, stone2)
        if stone1 + stone2 == 0:
            print('Вы выиграли!')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Увы, решение неправильное, LMS пишет, мол, ИИ должен был выиграть, но проиграл, буду разбираться с преподавателем, спасибо вам за неравнодушие!

Comment: я ж говорю, программа скучная без стратегии. Подумайте, как надо играть. Если, например, вы оставите две кучки по одному камню, вы проиграли